# CiviCRM and WordPress User Groups and Permissions

Tags: wordpress, permissions

We are trying to set-up user accounts for use on both our WordPress club website and CiviCRM but just can't figure out how to get the permissions piece to work.

The "CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync" plugin has allowed us to create the user accounts and sync between the two systems for about 80-90% of our members, so that is now working. What we can't figure out is how to set the WordPress permissions to be based off of CiviCRM groups (WordPress uses Roles/Responsibilities).

We acquired a few plugins called "Press Permit Core" and "Capability Manager Enhanced" thinking they would help, but it hasn't. It shouldn't be this difficult to manage user groups and security from CiviCRM to WordPress. Any guidance that you can provide is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync is compatible with both the [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) and [Groups](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/) plugins. The former grants WordPress users the 'restrict_content' capability when they have a membership, whilst the latter allows capabilities that are generated by CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync to be mapped to user groups. Either that, or you can roll your own functionality by mapping memberships to roles or capabilities.